# Book reader for website

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, css, flash

Do you know any good solutions for converting a HTML rich text to a paginated book ?
I used a CKEditor to let the user input the desired text.
Now I am trying to display the content in a Book like environment. Preferably a Javascript/CSS one but Flash is OK too.
Thought about jPaginate , jquery plugin.
The text can be formatted with 2-3 text styles and can contain images.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If Flash I would say some flipping book, like [PageFlip](http://pageflip.hu/free.php). Flash is still quite limited in working with html tags though.

Here is a list of the supported html tags: http://www.designswan.com/archives/tags-support-in-htmltext-flash-as3.html

Rob

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I came up with another solution though. Not using flash.CKEditor Print page break is a button in the editor which adds a div. Let the user insert the page breaks himself as that is what he desired and just split the text and print it with just HTML, and some nifty Jquery effects.